# Run Second Select statement if the first SQL statement return NULL(or nothing)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have two `SELECT` statements. I want to run the second SQL statement if the first statement return nothing or `NULL`.

First `Select` statement:

```
SELECT 
    k.key_no, concat(k.key_no,'-', key_title) 
FROM
    dbo.ff_keyword k
LEFT JOIN 
    ff_fundkey f ON f.key_no = k.key_no
LEFT JOIN
    ff_fundinfo fi ON fi.fund_no = f.fund_no
WHERE
    f.fund_no = '1'
ORDER BY 
    key_no, key_title
OFFSET 1 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Second statement:

```
SELECT 
    k.key_no, concat(k.key_no,'-', key_title) 
FROM 
    dbo.ff_keyword k
```

I tried to use `ISNULL` but I think that cannot be the solution. Is there anyway to do this in SQL Server 2016? I am not sure if the `Case When` can be the solution.

ISNULL code:

```
SELECT
    ISNULL((SELECT k.key_no, concat(k.key_no,'-', key_title) 
            FROM dbo.ff_keyword k
            LEFT JOIN ff_fundkey f ON f.key_no = k.key_no
            LEFT JOIN ff_fundinfo fi ON fi.fund_no = f.fund_no
            WHERE f.fund_no = '1'
            ORDER BY key_no, key_title
            OFFSET 1 ROWS
            FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY),
           (SELECT k.key_no, concat(k.key_no,'-', key_title) 
            FROM dbo.ff_keyword k))
```

Here is the error when I used `ISNULL`:

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
>   Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
>
> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
>   Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is a CTE:

```
with first as (
      select k.key_no, concat(k.key_no, '-', key_title) as col
      from dbo.ff_keyword k join
           ff_fundkey f
           on f.key_no = k.key_no left join
           ff_fundinfo fi
           on fi.fund_no = f.fund_no
      where f.fund_no = '1'
      order by key_no, key_title
      offset 1 rows fetch next 1 rows only
     )
select f.* --I think we can only select from first not other tables
from first f
union all
select k.key_no, concat(k.key_no, '-', key_title) 
from dbo.ff_keyword k
where not exists (select 1 from first);
```

Note that I changed the first `left join` to an inner join.  The `where` clause does that anyway, so the `left join` is misleading.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I tried it but have an error says 'Msg 107, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
The column prefix 'f' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query.'

Comment: I think I cannot use the alias name that are in CTE

Comment: I have change the 'f' to 'first'  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make it as IF EXISTS Clause as given below:

```
   IF EXISTS (
        SELECT k.key_no, CONCAT (k.key_no, '-', key_title)
        FROM dbo.ff_keyword k
        LEFT JOIN ff_fundkey f ON f.key_no = k.key_no
        LEFT JOIN ff_fundinfo fi ON fi.fund_no = f.fund_no
        WHERE f.fund_no = '1'
        ORDER BY key_no, key_title OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
        )
BEGIN
    SELECT k.key_no, CONCAT (k.key_no, '-', key_title)
    FROM dbo.ff_keyword k
    LEFT JOIN ff_fundkey f ON f.key_no = k.key_no
    LEFT JOIN ff_fundinfo fi ON fi.fund_no = f.fund_no
    WHERE f.fund_no = '1'
    ORDER BY key_no, key_title OFFSET 1 ROWS

    FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT k.key_no, CONCAT (k.key_no, '-', key_title)
    FROM dbo.ff_keyword k
END
```